# No sound coming from the computer

Tags: audio, drivers, sound-card

I have an issue related to the onboard sound card of my desktop PC. Basically, yesterday i was swapping a few video cards inside my computer to test them, and suddenly, i noticed that there was a noticeable noise coming from my computer's sound card during a windows session (like a background hiss and some squeaky noise along with it).

I thought that I touched something (although i was careful and the computer was powered off when I was working inside it) and i tried to repair this issue (I have tried some things, see below) but nothing worked so far.

**System specifications:**

- MSI H61M-P20 motherboard (LGA 1155, from 2012) /w i3 CPU
- Realtek HDAudio ALC887
- 8 GB of system memory
- SATA hard drive (WD)
- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit

**What I have  tried so far:**

- reinstalled the drivers (i tried both Realtek and Windows drivers)
- restored BIOS to default settings
- tried with another OS installation (another hard drive)

I have noticed a few things meanwhile:

- with the windows driver, the sound card keeps enabling/disabling every few seconds by itself
- with the Realtek driver, if i turn up the volume to 100% i can barely hear actual sounds and the noise in the same time
- the sound works fine through my GPU's HDMI port
- there is no hissing noise at all in safe mode

Is the sound card dead? Or is it not configured?

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using? It is possible your default sound device is set to a different output, or your GPU is taking precedence over your existing sound configuration.

Comment: The GPU is a GTX 650, but even if i disable it's sound capabilities, it happens the same. I've been using the computer with the nvidia sound disabled for years and it worked great. Although i should try this with the onboard graphics only.Hmm..

Comment: I have tried with the onboard graphics only, but no results.